# Remove vowels from a word one by one

Tags: c, string

I have to write a program that removes the vowels from a word one by one. That means that it takes each vowel alphabetically and if that vowel is in the word, it removes all of its appearances and then prints the word. Then it does this for all of the other vowels. For example, for the word `programming`, the output would be:

```
progrmming
progrmmng
prgrmmng
```

Again, if a vowel has multiple appearances, all of its appearances are removed in one "step". Here's what I've tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char word[100],vowels[]={'a','e','i','o','u'},result[100];
    int n,nv=sizeof(vowels)/sizeof(char),d=0;
    fgets(word,100,stdin);
    n=strlen(word);
    for(int j=0;j<nv;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(&vowels[j], &word[i]) != 0) {
                result[i] = word[i];
                d++;
            }
        }
        result[d]='\0';
        printf("%s",result);
    }
}
```

I know that this code isn't good and that it won't solve the problem properly, but it should at least make the first change correctly, but instead it leaves the word unchanged. I used the debugger in Clion and it seems like `strcmp` returns `-1` even if the current letter and vowel are identical...

Comment: The `strcmp` function compares strings, not characters. Test `vowels[j] == word[i]`.

Comment: `strcmp` compares null-terminated byte strings, you want to just check if two characters are identical: `if (vowels[j] == word[i])`

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `d` to zero inside the outer loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the string into itself (in-place) with two pointers, a source and destination, that iterate over the string.

If the current char is the current vowel nothing is done. Otherwise, the char is copied to the destination pointer [which is incremented]. The source pointer is incremented on each iteration.

Here's some sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void
novow(char *str)
{
    char *dst;
    const char *src;
    const char *vowel = "aeiou";

    // show the original string
    printf("%s\n",str);

    // eliminate all vowels in order
    for (int vow = *vowel++;  vow != 0;  vow = *vowel++) {
        dst = str;
        src = str;

        // copy over chars one-by-one
        int clip = 0;
        for (int chr = *src++;  chr != 0;  chr = *src++) {
            // char is vowel -- skip it but remember that we saw it
            if (chr == vow)
                clip = 1;

            // not the current vowel -- copy it over
            else
                *dst++ = chr;
        }
        *dst = 0;

        // show the changed string
        if (clip)
            printf("%s\n",str);
    }
}

void
dotest(const char *str)
{

    char *buf = strdup(str);
    novow(buf);
    free(buf);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    int sep = 0;
    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        if (sep)
            printf("\n");
        sep = 1;
        dotest(*argv);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

For the following arguments:

```
quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs booking
```

Here is the output:

```
quick
quck
qck

brown
brwn

fox
fx

jumps
jmps

over
ovr
vr

the
th

lazy
lzy

dogs
dgs

booking
bookng
bkng
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If we compare the final source and destination pointers for equality, we can eliminate the extra `clip` variable above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void
novow(char *str)
{
    char *dst;
    const char *src;
    const char *vowel = "aeiou";

    // show the original string
    printf("%s\n",str);

    // eliminate all vowels in order
    for (int vow = *vowel++;  vow != 0;  vow = *vowel++) {
        dst = str;
        src = str;

        // copy over chars one-by-one
        for (int chr = *src++;  chr != 0;  chr = *src++) {
            // not the current vowel -- copy it over
            if (chr != vow)
                *dst++ = chr;
        }
        *dst++ = 0;

        // show the changed string
        if (dst != src)
            printf("%s\n",str);
    }
}

void
dotest(const char *str)
{

    char *buf = strdup(str);
    novow(buf);
    free(buf);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    int sep = 0;
    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        if (sep)
            printf("\n");
        sep = 1;
        dotest(*argv);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the terminating `\0` byte being inserted at the new end of the string.  Maybe I just missed it.

Comment: @MikeRobinson There's a `*dst = 0;` after the copy loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of `strcmp`... The `str` in the name implies *strings* (null-terminated arrays of characters). It can't be used to compare single characters.

If you remember that a `char` value is just a small integer, it shouldn't come as a big surprise that characters can be compared using plain `==` or `!=`, as in:

```
if (vowels[j] != word[i]) { ... }
```

---

The above `strcmp` issue is only *one* part of your problem, the other is your use of the index `i` for both the source and destination in the assignment:

```
result[i] = word[i];
```

This will lead to you putting "holes" in the `result` array, where you don't set any value.

You should be using `d` as the index for the `result` array:

```
result[d] = word[i];
```

And that's not all, the logic of the loops and the checks isn't correct.

I suggest you create a new function `isvowel` which takes one character as argument and returns a "true" value if that character is a vowel.

Then you could have a single loop over the input string `word`, check if the current character is not a vowel and then copy the character. Perhaps something like this:

```
for (unsigned i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(word); ++i)
{
    if (!isvowel(word[i]))
    {
        result[j++] = word[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just  compare  char  value  not  string

Like  this
Words[i] == vowel[j]